# Servlet open PDF in new window

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, servlets

I have a requirement in our application to open PDFs in a new window. The requirement is to open a new window only if the PDF data is available. I am making a service call to get the PDF content as a **bytearray**. If the service returns a PDF bytearray then I only need to open a new window to show the PDF. I am using jQuery and Spring.

I tried with `window.open target="_blank"`. But the problem is it opens a window immediately before hitting the server. Below is my controller code to flush the PDF.

```
response.setContentLength(pdfBytes.length);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(pdfBytes);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

I tried with Ajax so that once I got the response I can do a `window.open` to open a window to show the PDF - but that too is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check for pdf content at the time (or before) of rendering page and show link with `target="_blank"` (if there is pdf content) or just plain text (if no content avaible).

Comment: The requirement is we will always display the link for the pdf while loading the page. Once the user clicks on the link, the server will return the pdf content. If the server returns data then I need to open it in new window.

Comment: Do you have an URL which may be opened in browser as PDF?

Comment: On click of the link, I am redirecting to a request mapping url in controller. From the controller I am calling service to get pdf as byte array.